# Using combinations of OR and AND filters with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm trying to work out a way to create a combination of `OR` and `AND` filters in RxJava. Here's what I've done so far:

```
public interface IFilter<T> extends Transformer<T, Boolean> {}

public class OrFilter implements IFilter<T> {
    private final Observable<IFilter<T>>    filters;

    public OrFilter(Iterable<IFilter<T>> filters) {
        this.filters = Observable.from(filters);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> call(Observable<T> o) {
        return filters
            .flatMap(f -> o.compose(f))
            .exists(b -> b);
    }
}

public class AndFilter implements IFilter<T> {
    private final Observable<IFilter<T>>    filters;

    public OrFilter(Iterable<IFilter<T>> filters) {
        this.filters = Observable.from(filters);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> call(Observable<T> o) {
        return filters
            .flatMap(f -> t.compose(f))
            .all(b -> b);
    }
}
```

Abstract class to create simple filters:

```
public abstract class BaseSimpleFilter<T> implements IFilter<T> {

    private Func1<T, Boolean>   filter;

    protected abstract Func1<T, Boolean> filter();

    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> call(Observable<T> observable) {
        if (this.filter == null) {
            this.filter = filter();
        }
        return observable
            .filter(this.filter)
            .exists(b -> true);
    }
}
```

That works nice and does what I expect. I've recently read ["Don't break the chain: use RxJava's `compose()` operator"](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/), so that's what I tried to do. The thing is I have here to combine `flatMap` with `compose` to achieve my goal, so the `compose` inside the `flatMap` loses a bit of its value. Plus, I'm worried this would be too costly in terms of process time.

Is there a better (more performant in terms of process time) Rx way to combine filters efficiently that I missed?